# Obtain the L1 imbalance measure for cem methodology in Matchit

Tags: r

Is there a way to obtain the L1 difference (as the one from the cem package) with Matchit?

I have looked through other questions and the documention but I can't seem to find an answer

Thanks,
Andriy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `L1.meas()` and `L1.profile()` functions from the `cem` package. The syntax for these two functions is the same. Here is how you would use them:

```r
with(m.out, cem::L1.meas(treat, X, weights = weights))
```

You do not need to change any arguments to match your data except the `m.out` variable, which should be the `matchit` object.

Comment: So basically I leave the 'treat' and 'X' arguments as they are even if they have different names in my dataset, that's right? - btw thanks a lot

Comment: Yes because those are components in the `matchit` object that are always named that way regardless of the names of your variables. Hope it helps. Remember that you need to specify a binning structure to use `L1.meas()`. I also recommend you try computing it manually on a test dataset and make sure the results line up; there are some bugs in `cem` that might affect your dataset.